# Scope of Google Logs API?

Tags: api, google-app-engine, rest, logging

Is the [Google Logs (Java) API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/logs/) only for querying logs of the GAE application where it is called from or can it be used more broadly for querying logs for all GAE applications that belong to the same account?

And it the second is not possible, does Google provide an [API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/) for retrieving status information (e.g. logs) about all applications under one account?

What I'd like to do is call such an API at regular intervals to ask e.g. if any recent HTTP requests resulted in errors: this would give a quick dashboard summary based on a subset of information (also) presented in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this isn't possible. But, you can download logs using appcfg (for any app) - maybe that is an option?